# Visual studio 2022 version 17.6.2 debug modules are not loading

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am unable to debug in the latest visual studio version 17.6.2 enterprise version. When I look into Debug modules, I see them as empty. I reinstalled the visual studio as well, still same issue. Anyone facing this?

Comment: I've had a few problems with 17.6.2, try deleteing the solutions .vs folder.

Comment: @user20716902 Tried but no luck